# Angular 2 electron project compiling is having problems

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, webpack, electron

I am coming back to a project I have not dealt with in a while, on a new machine and I am having problems compiling and running it.

This is my configuration:

Node version v6.11.1
NPM version 3.10.10

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "ConnectToolkit",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my proj",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron main.js",
    "build": "webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "distribute": "electron-packager . Electrogram --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --out=releases/ --overwrite --icon=src/assets/images/electrogram  --asar"
  },
  "author": "Andy Armstrong",
  "license": "See Licence.txt ",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.37",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.33",
    "@types/webpack": "^1.12.35",
    "@types/zone.js": "0.0.27",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "electron": "^1.4.5",
    "electron-packager": "^8.2.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.5",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.11",
    "electron-reload": "^1.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.6",
    "uglify-js": "^2.7.4",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^3.1.2",
    "electron-window-state": "^3.1.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "ftp": "^0.3.10",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.2.1",
    "ng2-popover": "0.0.11",
    "node-persist": "^2.0.7",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ssh2": "^0.5.4",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.40",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.26"
  }
}
```

When I run `npm install` I get the following output:

```
npm i
npm WARN deprecated ng2-popover@0.0.11: name updated to match new angular versions. install ngx-popover instead
npm WARN deprecated electron-prebuilt@1.4.13: electron-prebuilt has been renamed to electron. For more details, see http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/08/16/npm-install-electron
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.6.2 should be installed with -g

> fsevents@1.1.2 install /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v48-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> electron@1.6.11 postinstall /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/electron
> node install.js


> electron-prebuilt@1.4.13 postinstall /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/electron-prebuilt
> node install.js

ConnectToolkit@0.0.1 /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit
├── @angular/common@2.4.10 
├── @angular/compiler@2.4.10 
├── @angular/core@2.4.10 
├── @angular/platform-browser@2.4.10 
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.10 
├── @angular/router@3.4.10 
├── @types/core-js@0.9.42 
├── @types/hammerjs@2.0.34 
├── @types/jasmine@2.5.53 
├── @types/node@6.0.84 
├── @types/selenium-webdriver@2.53.42 
├─┬ @types/webpack@1.12.36 
│ └─┬ @types/uglify-js@2.6.29 
│   └── @types/source-map@0.5.0 
├── @types/zone.js@0.0.27 
├─┬ css-loader@0.25.0 
│ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.22.0 
│ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3 
│ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1 
│ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.5 
│ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.1.1 
│ │ │ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.1 
│ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
│REMOVED SOME DUE TO SIZE!
│   │   ├─┬ rimraf@2.6.1 
│   │   │ └─┬ glob@7.1.2 
│   │   │   ├── fs.realpath@1.0.0 
│   │   │   ├── inflight@1.0.6 
│   │   │   ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.4 
│   REMOVE MORE DUE TO SIZE!
│ │ ├── async@0.2.10 
│ │ └─┬ yargs@3.10.0 
│ │   ├── camelcase@1.2.1 
│ │   └── cliui@2.1.0 
│ ├─┬ watchpack@0.2.9 
│ │ └── async@0.9.2 
│ └─┬ webpack-core@0.6.9 
│   └─┬ source-map@0.4.4 
│     └── amdefine@1.0.1 
├─┬ xml2js@0.4.17 
│ ├── sax@1.2.4 
│ └─┬ xmlbuilder@4.2.1 
│   └── lodash@4.17.4 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.6.26

npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.7.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN ConnectToolkit@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN ConnectToolkit@0.0.1 license should be a valid SPDX license expression
```

This doesn't look good :

```
reflect-metadata@0.1.10 
├─┬ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
```

and also `└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.6.26` as well as the various messages at the bottom of the output. Not sure how to fix any of those.

If I *ignore* those messages - and go ahead and try to compile the project by running : `npm run build` which executes command : `webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached`

I get the following errors:

```
npm run build

> ConnectToolkit@0.0.1 build /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit
> webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached

 27% 2/7 build modulests-loader: Using typescript@2.4.2 and /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
5916ms build modules      
14ms seal
21ms optimize
40ms hashing
58ms create chunk assets
19ms additional chunk assets
2273ms optimize chunk assets
617ms optimize assets
73ms emit
Hash: 919b8c47d992c219c128
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 9049ms
          Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    @angular.js  767 kB       0  [emitted]  @angular
         app.js  2.9 MB       1  [emitted]  app
      common.js  145 kB       2  [emitted]  common
@angular.js.map  919 kB       0  [emitted]  @angular
     app.js.map  3.5 MB       1  [emitted]  app
  common.js.map  167 kB       2  [emitted]  common
   [0] multi @angular 52 bytes {0} [built]
       factory:0ms building:1ms = 1ms
   [0] multi common 28 bytes {2} [built]
       factory:1ms building:0ms = 1ms
 [346] external "events" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:0ms building:1ms
 [347] external "fs" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [348] external "timers" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [349] external "crypto" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [350] external "_http_client" 42 bytes {0} [not cacheable] [optional]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [367] external "tls" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [368] external "zlib" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [369] external "net" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [370] external "util" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:1ms building:0ms
 [372] external "stream" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:0ms building:0ms
 [376] external "buffer" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:0ms building:0ms
 [386] external "readline" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:0ms building:0ms
 [391] external "path" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:0ms building:0ms
 [402] external "electron" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:4ms building:0ms
 [404] external "child_process" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:0ms building:0ms
 [412] external "string_decoder" 42 bytes {1} [not cacheable]
       ... -> factory:0ms building:0ms
    + 579 hidden modules

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast.d.ts
(433,63): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/aot/compiler.d.ts
(44,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts
(342,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts
(344,28): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts
(346,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts
(348,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts
(350,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/compile_metadata.d.ts
(352,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts
(11,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/shared_styles_host.d.ts
(22,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts
(22,37): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/common/src/directives/ng_class.d.ts
(48,34): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_adapter.d.ts
(97,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/browser_adapter.d.ts
(79,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts
(7,59): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/rxjs/operator/toPromise.d.ts
(10,26): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/rxjs/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.d.ts
(23,22): error TS2415: Class 'WebSocketSubject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'AnonymousSubject<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type '<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>'.
      Type 'WebSocketSubject<R>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<T>'.
        Types of property 'operator' are incompatible.
          Type 'Operator<any, R>' is not assignable to type 'Operator<any, T>'.
            Type 'R' is not assignable to type 'T'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts
(66,60): error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/rxjs/Subject.d.ts
(16,22): error TS2415: Class 'Subject<T>' incorrectly extends base class 'Observable<T>'.
  Types of property 'lift' are incompatible.
    Type '<T, R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<T>' is not assignable to type '<R>(operator: Operator<T, R>) => Observable<R>'.
      Type 'Observable<T>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<R>'.
        Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts
(24,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/default_keyvalue_differ.d.ts
(28,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(12,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang.d.ts
(13,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Set'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts
(87,123): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.d.ts
(87,165): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Map'.

ERROR in ./src/app/settings/settings.component.ts
(5,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/settings/settings.component.ts
(6,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/settings/settings.component.ts
(13,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/settings/settings.component.ts
(14,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/ssh-service/ssh.service.ts
(1,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/ssh-service/ssh.service.ts
(2,26): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/ftp-service/ftp.service.ts
(1,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/ftp-service/ftp.service.ts
(2,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/ftp-service/ftp.service.ts
(3,18): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/files-service/files.service.ts
(1,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/files-service/files.service.ts
(2,10): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/src/app/services/canvas/canvasService.ts
(2,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/api-service/api.service.ts
(97,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/services/api-service/api.service.ts
(98,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-details/server.details.component.ts
(8,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-details/server.details.component.ts
(9,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-browser/server.browser.component.ts
(4,12): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-browser/server.browser.component.ts
(6,19): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-browser/server.browser.component.ts
(7,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-browser/server.browser.component.ts
(10,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-browser/server.browser.component.ts
(14,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/server-browser/server.browser.component.ts
(15,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/page-1/page.1.component.ts
(5,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/page-1/page.1.component.ts
(6,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/api-list/api.list.component.ts
(6,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/api-list/api.list.component.ts
(7,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/api-detail/api.detail.component.ts
(8,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/api-detail/api.detail.component.ts
(9,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/api-browser/api.browser.component.ts
(12,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/api-browser/api.browser.component.ts
(13,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/api-browser/api.browser.component.ts
(77,17): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
(6,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
(7,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/src/customDefinitions.d.ts
(1,15): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Notification'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'core-js'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'hammerjs'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'selenium-webdriver'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'source-map'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'uglify-js'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack'.

ERROR in /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/tsconfig.json
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'zone.js'.
```

As you can clearly see - this may be a dependency error, but this used to work with this package.json....so perhaps this is to do with a different version of npm / node being used.

Please help either way so I can get a clean compile and run my project again!

----- Update:-------

I have run `npm-check-updates` - and updated all `package.json` dependencies suggested:

```
 npm-check-updates -u
[INFO]: You can also use ncu as an alias
Using /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit/package.json
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠼ :
 @angular/common                           ^2.1.2  →    ^4.3.1 
 @angular/compiler                         ^2.1.2  →    ^4.3.1 
 @angular/core                             ^2.1.2  →    ^4.3.1 
 @angular/platform-browser                 ^2.1.2  →    ^4.3.1 
 @angular/platform-browser-dynamic         ^2.1.2  →    ^4.3.1 
 @angular/router                           ^3.1.2  →    ^4.3.1 
 electron-window-state                     ^3.1.0  →    ^4.1.1 
 ng2-popover                               0.0.11  →    0.0.14 
 rxjs                               5.0.0-beta.12  →     5.4.2 
 systemjs                                ^0.19.40  →  ^0.20.15 
 zone.js                                  ^0.6.26  →   ^0.8.14 
 @types/node                              ^6.0.46  →   ^8.0.14 
 @types/selenium-webdriver               ^2.53.33  →    ^3.0.4 
 @types/webpack                          ^1.12.35  →    ^3.0.4 
 @types/zone.js                            0.0.27  →    0.5.12 
 css-loader                               ^0.25.0  →   ^0.28.4 
 file-loader                               ^0.9.0  →   ^0.11.2 
 ts-loader                                 ^1.0.0  →    ^2.3.1 
 uglify-js                                 ^2.7.4  →   ^3.0.25 
 webpack                                  ^1.13.3  →    ^3.3.0
```

I then ran `npm run build` which resulted in :

```
npm run build

> ConnectToolkit@0.0.1 build /Users/andy.armstronguk.ibm.com/Documents/Personal/ConnectToolkit
> webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'debug'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   The 'debug' property was removed in webpack 2.
   Loaders should be updated to allow passing this option via loader options in module.rules.
   Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to switch loaders into debug mode:
   plugins: [
     new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
       debug: true
     })
   ]
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
```

This suggests the webpack.config.js has out of date syntax - can you please help me update this :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin;

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  debug: true,

  entry: {
    '@angular': [
      'rxjs',
      'reflect-metadata',
      'zone.js'
    ],
    'common': ['es6-shim'],
    'app': './src/app/app.ts'
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['','.ts','.js','.json', '.css', '.html']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts',
        exclude: [ /node_modules/, /releases/ ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|html)$/,
        loader: 'raw'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'url?limit=10000'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({ names: ['@angular', 'common'], minChunks: Infinity })
  ],
  target:'electron-renderer'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the packages to latest version by using this command **npm-check-updates**. Try to download **Typescript** and install from this link *https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html#download-links*. 
While Installing close the VS

Comment: Hi. Thanks - I have done this and updated my question above with the next hurdle - please help me fix the webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1):

Try to change webpack.config.js:

And remove empty string from resolve

```
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts','.js','.json', '.css', '.html']
  },


 plugins: [
           new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
             /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ 
options : { 
          htmlLoader : { 
              minimize : false 
                   } 
    }
  }) 


]
```

Comment: This looks like a fragment of the file - what would the entire file look like, pasting just that inside webpack.config.js results in it complaining about the ',' on line 3!

Comment: In extensions remove empty string

Comment: Sorry I don't think you understand me - what you have pasted above - is that meant to be the entire contents of webpack.config.js? If so - it doesn't look syntactically correct. If it is not correct - can you alter you answer to include the complete contents of this file?

Comment: Vignesh can you please double check my comment above ^^

Comment: It seems as though helpers can't be resolved to anything when I try pieceing the complete file together : ReferenceError: helpers is not defined

Comment: Refer the link for webpack bundling: https://angular.io/guide/webpack @RenegadeAndy